# Make UINavigationBar title unchanged during navigation stack

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationitem

So, All i want is my app title text to be fixed for all `UIViewController` during push/pop on navigation stack. Currently it comes in and goes out with sliding in/out effect, i don't want title text to be animated as it never gonna change.

Can it be possible by anyways ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create a custom container view controller unless you depend on features of UINavigationController heavily.

Comment: To expand on Mert's comment, just use a UINavigationBar in a UIViewController, instead of a UINavigationController.